# Where does this video of Lucas talking about the Force come from?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, george-lucas

I saw this video on youtube, but I was wondering where it comes from originally:

Was it a DVD special feature (if so, what release), or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *Star Wars* Blu-Rays - the Bonus Features

The interview in question is from the bonus features on the *Star Wars* Blu-ray release. You can tell by the orange-ish outline-thingy around the border of the actual video. Compare with some *other* Blu-ray release features below: